# При изменении или создании нового файла, Pycharm принимает его как .txt

Tags: pycharm

Доброго времени суток! Имеется такая проблема, установил `Pycharm`, открываю `.py` файлы, редактор видит что это пайтон синтаксис. но если я внесу какие-либо изменения и сохраню, или же создам новый файл, поддержка синтаксиса пропадает и текст отображается как в обычном редакторе :(

прощу помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File | Settings...` и проверите / добавте `*.py`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]